# How do I fix the height of the multi=True in Dash Dropdown?

Tags: python, css, plotly-dash

**app.py** - Focused on the dropdown

```
from data_processing import *

import dash
import dash_core_components as dcc
import dash_html_components as html
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from dash.dependencies import Output, Input

data = clean_data()

external_stylesheets = [
    {
        "href": "https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?"
        "family=Lato:wght@400;700&display=swap",
        "rel": "stylesheet",
    }
]
app = dash.Dash(__name__, external_stylesheets=external_stylesheets)

app.layout = html.Div(
    children=[
        html.Div(
            children=[
                html.P(children="", className="header-emoji"),
                html.H1(children="WQMS Analytics", className="header-title"),
                html.P(
                    children="Analyze the water parameters that measure the quality of water at multiple stations in Malaysia.",
                    className="header-description",
                ),
            ],
            className="header",
        ),
        html.Div(
            children=[
                dcc.Upload(
                    id="upload-data",
                    children=html.Div(
                        [
                            "Drag and Drop or ",
                            html.A(
                                "Select a file",
                            ),
                        ]
                    ),
                    style={
                        # "width": "1024px",
                        "height": "60px",
                        "lineHeight": "60px",
                        "borderWidth": "1px",
                        "borderStyle": "dashed",
                        "borderRadius": "5px",
                        "textAlign": "center",
                        "margin": "10px",
                    },
                ),
                html.Div(id="ouput-data-upload"),
            ],
        ),
        html.Br(),
        html.Br(),
        html.Br(),
        html.Br(),
        html.Br(),
        html.Div(
            children=[
                html.Div(
                    children=[
                        html.Div(children="Variable(s)", className="menu-title"),
                        dcc.Dropdown(
                            id="variable-filter",
                            options=[
                                {"label": wq_var, "value": wq_var}
                                for wq_var in np.sort(data.columns)
                            ],
                            value="",  # Means all variable
                            placeholder="Select variable(s)",
                            multi=True,
                            clearable=True,
                            className="dropdown",
                            # style={"display": "inline-block"},
                        ),
                    ],
                    id="dd-wrapper",
                ),
                html.Div(
                    children=[
                        html.Button(
                            "Generate All Graphs",
                            id="all-button",
                            className="button",
                        ),
                        html.Button(
                            "Correlation Matrix",
                            id="corr-button",
                            className="button",
                        ),
                        html.Button(
                            "Boxplot",
                            id="bx-button",
                            className="button",
                        ),
                        html.Button(
                            "Overall Trend",
                            id="trend-button",
                            className="button",
                        ),
                    ],
                    className="btn-group button",
                ),
            ],
            className="menu",
            # children=[html.Div()]
        ),
    ]
)


@app.callback(
    [
        Output("corr-plot", "figure"),
        Output("box-plot", "figure"),
        Output("trend-plot", "figure"),
    ],
    [Input("variable-filter", "value")],
)
def display_all_graphs():
    pass


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run_server(debug=True, port=80)
```

**style.css** - Focused on the dropdown

```
body {
    font-family: "Lato", sans-serif;
    margin:0;
    background-color: #F7F7F7;
}

.header {
    /* background-color: #015aff; */
    background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom right, rgb(1, 217, 255) , rgb(5, 28, 231));
    /* height: 288px; */
    height: 200px;
    padding: 16px 0 0 0;
    /* display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: center */
}

.header-emoji {
    font-size: 48px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    text-align: center;
}

.header-title {
    color: #FFFFFF;
    font-size: 48px;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-align: center;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

.header-description {
    color: #CFCFCF;
    margin: 4px auto;
    text-align: center;
    max-width: 384px;
}

.wrapper {
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-left: auto;
    max-width: 1024px;
    padding-right: 10px;
    padding-left: 10px;
    margin-top: 32px;
}

.card {
    margin-bottom: 24px;
    box-shadow: 0 4px 6px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.18);
}

.menu {
    height: 190px;
    width: 912px;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-evenly;
    padding-top: 24px;
    margin: -80px auto 0 auto;
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
    box-shadow: 0 4px 6px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.18);
}

.Select-control {
    /* width: 256px; */
    width: 500px;
    height: 48px;
}

.Select--single > .Select-control .Select-value, .Select-placeholder {
    line-height: 48px;
}

.Select--multi .Select-value-label {
    line-height: 32px;
}

.menu-title {
    margin-bottom: 6px;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 18px;
    color: #0655bc;
}

#dd-wrapper .Select--multi .Select-value{
    background-color: aliceblue;
    color: #0655bc;
}

#dd-wrapper .VirtualizedSelectFocusedOption {
    background-color: skyblue;
}
    
.btn-group .button {
    background-color:  #0655bc;
    border: 1px solid #a8bbd4;
    border-radius: 15px;
    color: #ffffff;
    padding: 15px 32 px;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 16px;
    /* font-weight: bold; */
    font-family:'Segoe UI', Tahoma, Geneva, Verdana, sans-serif;
    cursor:pointer;
    width: 200px;
    height:40px;
    display: block;
    /* box-shadow: 0 12px 16px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.24), 0 17px 50px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.19); */
}
.btn-group .button:not(:last-child){
    border-bottom: none; /*prevent double borders*/
}

.btn-group .button:hover {
    background-color: #0655bc;
}
```

Not sure if this makes sense, but this is where I'm at and I want to make sure that the box does not dynamically resize. As seen from the pic linked below, my selected dropdown values are behaving like that, overflowing the box, if possible, I'd like to know how I can instead enable a scroll in the selected field box.

[As new items are added from the dropdown list, it goes over the border.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i0ndc.png)

Comment: Please include your code in the question. Otherwise it’s difficult to help.

Comment: @BasvanderLinden Added. Thanks.